# FOC algorithm for BLDC motor and rotor position estimation via IMU

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, motors, control-theory, pid-control

I would like to implement the Field Oriented Control (FOC) algorithm on my STM32 board for controlling a 3 phases sensorless BLDC motor.

By googling I found a very interesting [Application Note from Texas Instruments](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprabq3/sprabq3.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj3-OvG8brQAhUMKcAKHTLRBFEQFggiMAE&usg=AFQjCNEpbD4Rea0AH-HvNzs4VAFAIYH5wQ) which explains very clearly how to apply the FOC algorithm for driving a sensorless 3 phase BLDC.

On page 10 of the application note, there is a block diagram of the algorithm and there is a block called **Sliding-Mode
Based
Rotor
Position Estimator**.

[image: Block diagram on page 10 of application note]

Since in my application I have an IMU (Inertial Measurment Unit) fixed on the shaft of the BLDC motor, I can get both rate and acceleration data.

Once combined the data into my Kalman Filter (outputs a quaternion), I have both speed and position information of the rotor.

1. **Can I use IMU's data for the rotor position, instead of estimating as shown?**
2. **Is it correct considering the rotor angle got from the IMU for closing the loop?**

Comment: Not familiar with an IMU, but if you can get the position from it, then the answer is simply yes.

Comment: I can get quaternions evaluated with my Kalman Filter and I can transform the quaternions into Euler angles (roll pitch and yaw) with a precision of 3 degrees. Is it enough for applying the FOC algorithm?